# Unable to create a excel using Apache POI SXSSFWorkbook class with shiftrows

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to create a excel work book using Apache POI SXSSFWorkbook class. But it is unable to me run the file if I use `shiftrows` method as given in the sample code below.

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.poi;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;

public class sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Blank workbook
        SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();

        //Create a blank sheet
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Data");

        //This data needs to be written (Object[])
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]> data = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>();
        data.put("1", new Object[]{"NAME", "LASTNAME", "Count"});
        data.put("2", new Object[]{"Amit", "Shukla", 1});
        data.put("13", new Object[]{"Ram", "Krish", 2});

        //Iterate over data and write to sheet
        Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
        int rownum = 0;
        for (String key : keyset) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object[] objArr = data.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                if (obj instanceof String) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                } else if (obj instanceof Integer) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
                }
            }
        }
        try {

             sheet.shiftRows(1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), 1, false, false);
                      Row insRow = sheet.createRow(1);
                       for (int k = 0; k < sheet.getRow(1).getLastCellNum(); k++) {
                            Cell insCell = insRow.createCell(k);
                            if (k == 0) {
                                insCell.setCellValue("Govind");
                            } else if (k == 1) {
                                insCell.setCellValue("Narayan");
                            } else {
                                insCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
                                insCell.setCellFormula("7");
                            }
                        }

            //Write the workbook in file system
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("excelSample.xlsx"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();

            System.out.println("excelSample.xlsx written successfully on disk.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getColumnName(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

But it throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: NotImplemented
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.shiftRows(SXSSFSheet.java:827)
    at com.howtodoinjava.demo.poi.sample.main(sample.java:50)` error message. What is the work around?

Comment: Switch to using regular XSSF, which does implement it?

Comment: Initially I tried using XSSF and it working fine. But I unable to open the generated excel file in MS Office 2003. That is why i modified it to SXSSFWorkbook as suggested in Apache POI site.

Comment: The Apache POI site only suggests using SXSSF if XSSF runs out of memory. Otherwise the files should be the same. Why wouldn't the file open? What errors did you get? Could POI open it? etc

Comment: I too get the above exception. But on different method.     java.lang.RuntimeException: Not Implemented
     at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.setRowGroupCollapsed(SXSSFSheet.java:1119)